# Start external VPN Software via Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, cucumber

I am writing tests with Selenium. Before every test, I should open a VPN connection. 
To do this, I should navigate to a website link, insert credentials, and when I click on Login, a pop up ask me to open the software on PC. Then it will connect automatically. 
Manually with my browser, it works, but when I start the test, it click on Login, and then I get: **"JRE" is not installed on your machine. Install "JRE" and retry.**
I don't know how to do this.
How can I fix this?

Comment: And do you have Java runtime engine installed?

Comment: Yes i do. Manually it works with Chrome, but when i start the test it shows me that error. 
I tried changing the driver to Firefox, and it works. 
I need to make it work on Chrome.

Comment: Please add your code and screen with the error message.